# How to receive file as chunks in Rails(To avoid temfile creation)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, chunked

I am building a Rails application where user can upload very huge files. So I planned to receive files as multiple chunks so that I can assemble chunks at the server side.
I searched about the streaming in Rails framework. I can find more information about down streaming(Server -> Client).

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/4/18/why-http-streaming/

http://www.intridea.com/blog/2012/5/24/building-streaming-rest-apis-with-ruby

Is there any way to receive files as chunks in Rails application without creating temfile?

Comment: Look into resumable file uploads. A quick Google search turned up the following link https://github.com/stakach/Resumable-Uploads

Comment: Sorry I put send instead of receive in my question.